# selenium-webdriver / ruby / rspec2 - start IE with clean session or clear cookies or private browsing

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, rspec2

I'm using `selenium-webdriver` with ruby and rspec2.

I have a lot of web test automation for which I need to use IE and I need to run each test with a clean session (specifically cookies cleared).

In this case selenium-webdriver is using `InternetExplorerDriver` (`IEDriverServer.exe`) for which the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) indicates:

> There are 2 solutions for problem with cookies (and another session
>   items) shared between multiple instances of InternetExplorer.
>
> The first is to start your InternetExplorer in private mode. After
>   that InternetExplorer will be started with clean session data and will
>   not save changed session data at quiting. To do so you need to pass 2
>   specific capabilities to driver: ie.forceCreateProcessApi with true
>   value and ie.browserCommandLineSwitches with -private value. Be note
>   that it will work only for InternetExplorer 8 and newer, and Windows
>   Registry `HKLM_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main` path should contain key TabProcGrowth with 0 value.
>
> The second is to clean session during InternetExplorer starting. For
>   this you need to pass specific ie.ensureCleanSession capability with
>   true value to driver. This clears the cache for all running instances
>   of InternetExplorer, including those started manually.

My question is simply this:
Can anybody give an example of how this would be done in Ruby / Rspec2.

For example, I currently have:

```
before(:each) do
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :internet_explorer
  @driver.manage.window.maximize
  @base_url = "https://www.example.com/"
  @accept_next_alert = true
  @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
  @verification_errors = []
end
```

How can I pass such IE parameters to the IE driver using Ruby / Rspec?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post a month old but just in case anyone still need it.
after I did some research I finally can start fresh IEDriver without any session or cookies for every each of the test. Here is the code:

```
before(:each) do
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities..internet_explorer('ie.ensureCleanSession' => true, 'ie.browserCommandLineSwitches' => 'private')
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:internet_explorer, :desired_capabilities => caps)
  @driver.manage.window.maximize
  @base_url = "https://www.example.com/"
  @accept_next_alert = true
  @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
end
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
before(:each) do
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :internet_explorer
  @driver.manage.window.maximize
  @base_url = "https://www.example.com/"
  @accept_next_alert = true
  @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
  @verification_errors = []
  @driver.manage.delete_all_cookies
end
```

From the gem docs http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Options

--- edited ---

It looks like there might be a bug in the Selenium IE driver that doesn't delete cookies https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5101

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion, but at the moment I would like to avoid using Capybara to keep things as simple as possible.  Right now, I use Selenium IDE to generate tests and export them to Ruby / Rspec, where they can easily be run by any browser.  I don't doubt that Capybara could resolve this issue, but I am reluctant to add Capybara to my workflow simply to resolve this IE cookie issue.  (Ideally, I would like a solution that works without adding any additional components to the workflow.)  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I edited my answer to not use Capybara (before you replied even...), does the `@driver.manage.delete_all_cookies` not work?

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, @driver.manage.delete_all_cookies does not appear to work.  (It does not work for me, and it does not seem to work for others who have tried it with Internet Explorer as well.)  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Apparently other people can't get the cookies to delete when using IE https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5101
Looks like a bug in Selenium